# Using a variable from a loop as header in the mail() of PHP

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to customize the "from" address in the mail function in PHP. Im reading the required variables from a CSV file and using the mail() to trigger the mail. While I'm trying to customize the "from" address using the headers parameter, I'm not able to trigger the mails "from" all email ID's of the csv file and only the last row of the CSV file is read. This is the script i used:

```
<?PHP
$file_handle = fopen("email.csv", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    $test = $line_of_text[1];
    $to = "myemail@email.com";
    $subject = $line_of_text[2];
    $message = $line_of_text[3];
    $headers = 'From:' . $test;
    mail ($to,$subject,$message, $headers);   
    print $test . "<BR>";
}
fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

While mail is triggered, it only triggers for the last row in the CSV file and not all rows. This means, if there are 7 rows, only the 7th row email is triggered. Can someone please help?

Comment: can't see any reason why it wouldn't call mail() 7 times. of cousre, you should be checking the return value from mail. maybe it is calling 7 times and failing because of other problems. you're just assuming nothing could ever go wrong.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I did check the return value of the mail function and figured out the issue. Basically, what is happening is, if the to and from domains are the same, the mail is not triggered, works perfect if they are not. Thanks again for your response.